# colnames and mutate on multiple dataframes

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, sapply

I have a problem with cleaning up my code. I understand I could type this all out but we don't want that obviously.
I have only dataframes in my global environment. They are all "data.frame".
I want to check the dimensions of all of them and put that in a tibble. I managed that somehow. I also would like to change their colnames() tolower() which works easy if I just type the name of the data.frame, but there's more than 2 and I want it done automatically. Then I also want to mutate all data.frames in the same way.

Small example of my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- data.frame(letters[1:2]) #To create the data
y <- data.frame(letters[3:4])
dfs <- as.list(ls()) #I take whatever is in my environment
```

I managed below to get a tibble of the dimensions:

```
z <- as_tibble(lapply(seq_along(dfs),
            function(j) dim(get(dfs[[j]]))), .name_repair = "unique")
colnames(z) <- dfs
```

Now for the colnames of all the data.frames stored in my list I basically want to perform this code:

```
colnames(dfs[[1]]) <- tolower(colnames(dfs[[1]])
```

but that returns NULL as I found out earlier. So I used get() in there to make it work for the dimensions.  But if I use get() to assign colnames it says it can't find function "get<-".
Since all colnames for all dataframes are the same (just different nrows()) I could save the lowercase colnames as value and use that, but that doesn't take away that it cant find the get<- function.

```
names <- tolower(colnames(x))
sapply(seq_along(dfs),
       function(j) colnames(get(dfs[[j]])) <- names)
*Error in colnames(get(dfs[[j]])) <- names : 
  could not find function "get<-"*
```

as for the mutating part I tried a for loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(dfs)){
  get(dfs[[i]]) <- get(dfs[[i]]) %>% mutate(cd = ab)
}
```

But it's the same issue.
Could anyone help clearing this problem for me? (and if a cleaner code for the dimensions is available that would be highly appreciated)

I am just trying to up my coding skills. I would have been long done if I just typed it all out but that defeats the purpose.
Thanks!
-JK

Comment: @rjen It does create a list with the names of the data.frames. Not the actual data.frames no. If that is needed to get my desired outcome and I have to change things that's all fine by me. I just want to avoid typing the same stuff for 23 data.frames.

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
lapply(dfs, function(x) transform(setNames(x, tolower(names(x))), X = c('a', 'b')))
```